# How to mount UUID under linux name /dev/sdx/

Tags: mount, partitioning, uuid

On my workstation after boot, sometimes the name for my same harddisk in linux changes from `/dev/sdg/`  to `/dev/sdi/`
How can I make this fixed, that the UUID is mounted exactly with the name `/dev/sda` for example?

The problem comes from  making a virtual machine from a raw file:

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename ~/.VirtualBox/win7.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sdg -partitions 2,3 -mbr ~/.VirtualBox/FAKE.mbr -relative
```

If now the name `/dev/sdg` changes to `/dev/sdi` my virtual machine has troubles to start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use a udev rule:

```
KERNEL=="sd[a-z][0-9]", SUBSYSTEM=="block", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", ATTRS{model}=="Crucial_CT480M50", SYMLINK+="bootdevice%n"
KERNEL=="sd?", SUBSYSTEM=="block", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", ATTRS{model}=="Crucial_CT480M50", SYMLINK+="bootdevice"
```

in a file /etc/udev/rules.d/mybootdevice.rules

(how to adapt the attributes to fit your devive look here : [here](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html))

Then restart udev:

```
sudo udevadm trigger
```

Then there will be a /dev/bootdevice

which is persistent after every boot!

Answer (score 5):

### Use /dev/disk/by-uuid/someUUID instead of /dev/sdaXN

You can use the UUID to device symlinks in the `/dev` filesystem:

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/fc48808f-8f06-47fc-a1fe-5d08ee9e0a40
lrwxr[...] 14:15 /dev/disk/by-uuid/fc48808f-8f06-47fc-a1fe-5d08ee9e0a40 -> ../../sdd1
```

The link could be used like

```
... -rawdisk /dev/disk/by-uuid/fc48808f-8f06-47fc-a1fe-5d08ee9e0a40 ...
```

Instead of UUIDs, labels can be used in the same way - for example, with the label "**data**":

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/data 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  4 14:15 /dev/disk/by-label/data -> ../../sde1
```

Try

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid 
ls -l /dev/disk/by-label
```

Independent of that, `UUID`s or labels can also be used in `/etc/fstab`, instead of the `/dev/sdXN` device files. (List labels with `sudo lsblk -o NAME,LABEL`)

Comment: thanks alot ! i will try this with the VBoxManage command ... dont know if that works

Comment: unfortunately, this does not solve the problem, because the VBoxCommand needs this stupud labels e.g. sda1 and so on... hm... any ideas?

Comment: You can use  `readlink` to resolve the symlink.